# Keep 10 records to create/update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4. I am calling an API, which returns Shop and photos. When it returns photos, it could be up to 10 photos.

Everytime I call the API, it will `find_or_initialize_by` a Shop, so that I always update the Shop details. At the same time, I also want to update the photos. There is no way to know whether the photos is the same or different, not even from the url. Different photo url could be same photos as created previously. There's no reference id, and I am not saving/downloading the photos in my server too.

I have the following code:

```
@shop = Shop.find_or_initialize_by(source_id: shop_params[:id])
@shop.photos.build(shop_params[:photos])
```

**Question**

Let's say when I first creat Shop A, the API returns with 4 photos. I save all 4 photos. I call the API again for Shop A, the API returns with 10 photos. I want to save these 10 photos. I don't mind if the previous 4 are destroyed or updated. How do I make this work? The total photos should be 10 after saving.

Then, I may call the API again, which returns 6 photos. Now I don't want to keep the previous 10 photos, but just the 6 photos.

In my view, I will call `@shop.photos`, which is essentially the latest photos (up to 10).

**Note**
The photos returned by API could be duplicate from the ones that I already have in my DB. That's the reason why I can't keep the previous photos.

Comment: Could you clarify this?  "There's no reference id, and I am not saving the photos in my database too".  Are the photos in your db?  Do you want to save them to your db?

Comment: @Swards Sorry, I meant "I am not saving/downloading the photos in my server too"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always delete previous records and create new photos.

```
@shop = Shop.find_or_initialize_by(source_id: shop_params[:id])
@shop.save_photos(shop_params[:photos])
```

in shop.rb

```
def save_photos(photos)
    self.photos.destroy_all
    self.photos.build(photos)
end
```

It is very not robust solution but will work

Comment: Thanks. What is more robust?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@shop.photos = Photo.new(shop_params[:photos])
```

This will just set `photos` to a new array.

Comment: This populates new set of photos. If I have existing 7 photos, and the second call to API returns 10, I will end up having 17 photos, which some of them could be duplicate. (I updated the question just to be clearer)

Comment: Just one query `Photo.new(shop_params[:photos])`  will initiate a single new Photo Object, isn't it??  While @shop.photos show a one to many relationship...I am confused???